# ExecuteNonQuery results in a Parameter mapping error

Tags: c#, ado.net

Hi I am trying to insert data to a database using ADO.NET.Here is my code.
This is my C# code:

```
 public void CreateBook(FormCollection collection)
        {
            string name = collection["BookName"];
            string author = collection["Author"];
            string description = collection["Description"];
            int category = int.Parse(collection["category"]);
            DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("AddBook", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(createParameter(name, "@Name"));
                command.Parameters.Add(createParameter(author, "@Author"));
                command.Parameters.Add(createParameter(description, "@Description"));
                command.Parameters.Add(createParameter(currentDate.Date, "@Date"));
                command.Parameters.Add(createParameter(category, "@CategoryId"));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        //there are 2 other overloads of this method
        private SqlParameter createParameter(string parameter , string parameterName) {
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = parameterName;
            param.Value = param;
            return param;
        }
```

And this is my SQL code:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddBook]
    @Name nvarchar(MAX),
    @Author nvarchar(MAX),
    @Description nvarchar(MAX),
    @Date date  ,
    @CategoryId int
 AS
    INSERT INTO Books (Name , Author , Description , PublicationDate , CategoryId)
    VALUES (@Name , @Author , @Description , @Date , @CategoryId)
```

When ExecuteNonQueryuery is being fired I get this error:

```
No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native type.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tip: You don't need to create a method like `createParameter`. Just use `new SqlParameter()` in `Parameters.Add()` method. More clear and simple IMO..

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this line is the most immediate problem:

```
param.Value = param;
```

You meant:

```
param.Value = parameter;
```

Otherwise you're trying to set the parameter *value* to the parameter itself, which is meaningless.

However, I would personally recommend specifying the type etc as well. You can get rid of your other methods, and just use calls like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = currentDate.Date;
// etc
```

Answer (score 2):

you're assigning the actual parameter to the parameter -  param.Value = param;